# ActiveX Controls Listbox_Click() event not triggering

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use a ActiveX Listbox but the click event will not trigger.

Basically I want to a user to click on the list box, activating it, then proceed to click on cells in a specified range which will then add that cells content to the Listbox until the user selects another ActiveX Control or a cell outside the specified range.

I post the code but I dont have any because it will need the click event but basically I planed on using a do while loop that will add the selected cell contents on a click event with some if statements that will deselect the listbox if a cell section occurs outside of the specified range or another control is selected.

Comment: double click your listbox control and you'll be automagically brought to the barebone of a `Private Sub ListBox1_Click()` event handler

Comment: I have the Private Sub ListBox1_Click() in the code for the sheet its in with the rest of my event handlers but when I exit out of Design Mode in Excel all my other controls work but that event does not happen. MultiSelect is set to 0 and it is Enabled. When in Design Mode, double clicking on the listbox jumps the VBA window to that sub.

Comment: show your `Private Sub ListBox1_Click() ` code

Comment: Private Sub DWGList_Click()

    Debug.Print "DWGList"
    
End Sub

All I have. It was made by double clicking on the listbox while in Design Mode

Comment: is your listbox filled with entries?

Comment: No, its blank when "Initialized". I have been having problems with renaming controls after placing them. I will get and error saying that there is an ambiguous name detected when its not. I close Excel and reopen and it works fine after that. Could there be another issue?

Comment: I wouldn't say. But with a blank list its click event would never fire!

Comment: Oh, ok! So would I just give it a blank line and ignore that line when pulling the info from the listbox? I guess I want this to behave more like a Selection Box...

Comment: Don't exactly get you, but you can always try that and watch what happens

Comment: We will see what what I can do. Thanks for all the help though!